# Multiple dynamic method calls or declaring a variable in Grails

Tags: grails

In my view, if I have a situation where I need to use a dynamic method (such as Domain.findByName("name")) in multiple places, would it be better to define a variable with  and refer to that, rather than have the dynamic method in multiple places? I know this seems like an obvious answer, but I just wanted to make sure Grails doesn't cache it or something, and indeed two DB calls are being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, grails will only cache "get" requests (i.e. Book.get(4)), if you don't set up any additional caching, you'll hit the database for each request (as you're seeing).

See [the 'caching queries' section of the grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2.2%20Caching%20Strategy) for more detail.

If you only want the call to be made once (which makes sense in a view since you'd want it to be consistent), I'd either do the query in the action and pass it in the model, or else you could also use the g:set in your view to set it (though this sounds like it's more appropriate for a controller or service).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to send the domain object to the view as part of the model, rather than calling `Domain.findByName("name")` from your view.

So in your controller method you'd want

```
def myAction = {
    def myObject = Domain.findByName("name")
    // do other stuff
    [myObject: myObject]
}
```

then in your view you can access it by

```
${myObject.property}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, and depending on the nature of your query and application usage model, findByName("name", [cache:true]) may also benefit other clients executing the action, if you have Hibernate 2nd level cache enabled.